# CodeIgniter is duplicating the SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am developing with CodeIgniter and after sometime I noticed that all the queries are being executed two times as the mySQL log bellow shows:

```
           55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1' OR addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1' OR addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=95
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2' OR skill_id='4' OR skill_id='13'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2' OR skill_id='4' OR skill_id='13'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=9
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='1' OR skill_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='1' OR skill_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='2' OR addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='2' OR addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=16
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='16'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='16'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='7'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='7'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=68
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='1' OR skill_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='1' OR skill_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='4'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=79
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2' OR skill_id='4' OR skill_id='6'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2' OR skill_id='4' OR skill_id='6'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='2' OR addon_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='2' OR addon_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=86
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='8' OR skill_id='13'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='8' OR skill_id='13'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='3' OR addon_id='4' OR addon_id='5' OR addon_id='8'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='3' OR addon_id='4' OR addon_id='5' OR addon_id='8'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=92
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='3' OR skill_id='6' OR skill_id='19'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='3' OR skill_id='6' OR skill_id='19'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=2
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='3' OR addon_id='4' OR addon_id='8'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='3' OR addon_id='4' OR addon_id='8'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=12
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='11'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='11'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=34
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='3'
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT user_display FROM user WHERE user_id=1
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),contest_create) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT TIMEDIFF(ADDDATE(contest_create, INTERVAL contest_duration DAY),NOW()) FROM contest WHERE contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT add_addon_id FROM addon_contest WHERE add_contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1'
       55 Query SELECT addon_name FROM addon WHERE addon_id='1'
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT required_skill_id FROM skill_contest WHERE required_contest_id=74
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_id='2'
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_status=2
       55 Query SELECT skill_name FROM skill WHERE skill_status=2
       55 Quit
```

The problem is when some INSERT query is run, then all information is being inserted twice, and looking at the order of the queries I can conclude that I am not calling the Model twice, but when I call "$this->db->query($sql)" this is being sent to mySQL twice.
Maybe I have some wrong database configuration in CodeIgniter, does any of you know what is happening?

Comment: Did you try with standalone call of a model, which makes a dummy query, to check if it's called twice. If it's not, the error is somewhere in the code, loops or something make a double call

Comment: Actually I didnt try it out of the model, but if there were some extra calls in the code the logs should be different. For example I have a function that SELECTs first and then right after it INSERTs, if this function is called twice the log should be "SELECT INSERT SELECT INSERT", but the log shows "SELECT SELECT INSERT INSERT".

Comment: Can you post an example of one of your models methods that is being called twice?

Comment: Everytime I call this function from codeigniter:
"$this->db->query($sql);". Codeigniter runs the $sql string query twice. But there is an interesting fact, if the string $sql has two or more Separate commands, like: "INSERT INTO user VALUES (1,2,3); INSERT INTO user VALUES (5,4,2);" , Codeigniter runs it just once. I was thinking maybe it is something related to the semicolon ";", but I'm not sure.

Comment: I have another question opened that actually it is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726961/codeigniter-is-duplicating-the-sql-queries

Comment: If you don't post your code, we won't be able to find it. We can assure it doesn't do this for the other thousands of people using CI, so it's in your code somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out that the _execute() function in CI_DB_pdo_driver inside the codeigniter system was not working properly, maybe it is because of the php version. Anyway I changed the code of the CodeIgniter from:

```
    function _execute($sql)
{
    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    $result_id = $this->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $result_id->execute();

    if (is_object($result_id))
    {
        if (is_numeric(stripos($sql, 'SELECT')))
        {
            $this->affect_rows = count($result_id->fetchAll());
            $result_id->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affect_rows = $result_id->rowCount();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->affect_rows = 0;
    }

    return $result_id;
}
```

TO:

```
    function _execute($sql)
{
    $sql = $this->_prep_query($sql);
    $result_id = $this->conn_id->prepare($sql);
    $result_id->execute();

    if (is_object($result_id))
    {
        if (preg_match('/^\s*"?(SELECT)\s+/i', $sql))
        {
            $this->affect_rows = count($result_id->fetchAll());
            $result_id->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->affect_rows = $result_id->rowCount();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->affect_rows = 0;
    }

    return $result_id;
}
```

The part that tests if the $sql contains a "SELECT" inside it was not working, so when I tried to INSERT the "$result_id->execute()" was being called two times.